# Encoding Issue in Android String

Tags: android

Encoding Problem in android String

Web service return below  string response

**ãñøþ1219**

but i  getting response like **����1219**

I am using below code to convert but it is not working

```
  URLEncoder.encode(result, "UTF-8");
```

Please Help Me how i can fix this problem

Thanks In Advance

Comment: I thin you want to call `URLDecoder.decode` instead of encode. However, that doesn't explain the printing problem.

Comment: i called both but not working

Comment: So the original wasn't in UTF-8 but nobody here knows what it is. You'll have to figure the encoding yourself, or at least post the byte values you're receiving and what characters you expect them to represent so someone can guess the encoding for you.

Answer (score 0):

you must use Unicode font in order to display correctly Unicode text.

Answer (score 0):

Most Android devices do not come with a complete set of Unicode fonts. Also in order to display Unicode text in a way that can be read properly you need to include a proper font for the script concerned.

Hence you can try as follows :

```
Typeface tf =Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "your_font.ttf");
text.setTypeface(tf,Typeface.BOLD);
text.setText(Html.fromHtml(your_text_with_unicode));
```

When you are getting response like ����1219, it is a font problem. When Android renders symbols as empty squares or the squares shown in above response,it means that Unicode support is working, but the font does not have those symbols. Adding to that the complex scripts like Indic scripts (e.g. Devanagari) require special rendering engine on top of that.

Comment: No need to display only internal use,